# Issue with dotNerInstaller Getting error "The installation package could not be opened. Verify..."

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, dotnetinstaller

When I create exe within the C:\Program Files\dotNetInstaller\bin folder, and run it, it works perfect, install perfect, but when I try to install that exe from any other location/path, the error appears "The installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it. etc....."
I created an exe and moved to another XP system, on that system, it again gives me error ?

whats the solution ? Is there any admin rights issue ?
I have tried with both TRUE and FALSE of Administrator_Required option.

any idea how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved now.
I should have written #CABPATH\ in the MSI->Package field. Before I was writing #TEMPPATH\

Answer (score 0):

I think you can should add the location:

```
 C:\Program Files\dotNetInstaller\bin
```

in the PATH environment variable. Follow the steps: Go to

```
My Computer->Right click->Properties->Advanced System Settings
->Click Environmental Variables. Now click PATH and then click EDIT.
```

In the variable value field, go to the end and append ';' (without quotes) and then add the above path.

Comment: Thanks nehal. But the issue is not this. I have resolved it. below is my answer.